# get_object_vars() vs. cast to array

Tags: php, arrays, object, casting, properties

Are there any differences between `get_object_vars($obj)` and `(array) $obj` ?

Both seem to return the public properties of the object.

Which is better?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is not exactly true.

`get_object_vars` is scope-sensitive and will return all *visible* properties excepting *static* properties regardless of their visbility. If you call it from outside your class, you'll only get the public members; from a derived class, you'll get the protected and public members; and from the class itself, you'll get all the members. The array keys represent the property names, and are not mangled.

The `(array)` cast returns, at least on PHP 5.3.0, all the object properties, public and otherwise. The name of the properties are mangled according to their protection level:

- `public`: not mangled, identical to property names
- `protected`: key name for property starts with a `*`
- `private`: key name for property starts with the name of the class

See [casting to an array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting) for more informations.

I hope you'll be able to better understand which one is the most appropriate for your situation.

Comment: To add, for the `(array)` cast, the `*` for protected and the *classname* for private members will be enclosed in null-bytes (`\x00`), so strictly it's `\x00*\x00` for protected members and likewise for the private members: `\x00className\x00`. Related: **[Array to Object and Object to Array in PHP - interesting behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325447/array-to-object-and-object-to-array-in-php-interesting-behaviour/6325631#6325631)**

Comment: Another difference (at least in PHP 5) : with `get_object_vars` the keys will be cast to int if they are numbers, where casting returns string indexes : https://3v4l.org/2Wb9j

Comment: One more to `(array)` is that it won't include `static` properties either regardless of their visibility.

Answer (score 3):

The `get_object_vars()` function is a clearer method of achieving the effect you want. Although casting it to an array is a solution as well, this behavior might change in later versions of PHP.

I don't know if there is an actual difference between the two methods but the arguments above would lead me to use the function.

Comment: Why should the array cast be less reliable in its behavior than the function? Do you have documentation supporting it?

Answer (score 2):

Better is what is what you actually need. get_object_vars() doesn’t show private and protected members. See [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php#47075) in the manual for an example.