# How can I convert an object to associative array in PHP?

Tags: php

As title suggests, My question is that how i can convert a php class to an associative array?
For example I've

```
class MyObject {
  private $size = null;
  private $length = null;
  private $width = null;

    public function getSize(){
        return $this->size;
    }

    public function setSize($size){
        $this->size = $size;
    }

    public function getLength(){
        return $this->length;
    }

    public function setLength($length){
        $this->length = $length;
    }

    public function getWidth(){
        return $this->width;
    }

    public function setWidth($width){
        $this->width = $width;
    }

}

//Now what i want is following

$abc = new MyObject();
$abc->width = 10;
$anArray = someFunction($abc);  
//This should generate an associative array
//Now associative array is accessible
echo $anArray['width]; // 10
```

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways that work slightly differently.

You can cast to an array:

```
$array = (array)$object;
```

there's a chapter on details and side-effects [in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting)

or use [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/get_object_vars).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512212/get-object-vars-vs-cast-to-array) about the differences.

Comment: Can you please define that how to use get_object_vars() to build an associative array?

Comment: @Aqeel Sorry if this comes across rude now, but did you actually [RTFM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM "Read the f*cking Manual") before asking Pekka to spoonfeed you the code? If so, please point out what is making difficulties.

Comment: @Gordon Sorry i'd a bit of confusion, I've solved my problems. Thanks.