# PHP Print keys from an object?

Tags: php, arrays, object, echo

I have an object BIRD and then there is [0] through [10] and each number has a subheading like "bug" or "beetle" or "gnat" and a value for each of those.

I want to print

```
BIRD 
    [0]
       bug = > value
```

I can't find out how to do this anywhere - there is talk of PUBLIC and PRIVATE and CLASS and that's where I fall off

Comment: Read this ... manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 98):

You could easily do it by type casting the object:

```
$keys = array_keys((array)$BIRD);
```

Comment: This ends up giving me `ArrayArray to string conversion` as the result..

Answer (score 56):

Similar to brenjt's response, this uses PHP's `get_object_vars` instead of type casting the object.

```
$array = get_object_vars($object);
$properties = array_keys($array);
```

Comment: Which is the more efficient approach?

Comment: After reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512212/get-object-vars-vs-cast-to-array get_object_vars is safer to use.

Answer (score 13):

If the 'object' is actually an associative array rather than a true object then `array_keys()` will give you what you need without warnings or errors.

On the other hand, if your object is a true object, then you will get a warning if you try use `array_keys()` directly.

You can extract the key-value pairs from an object as an associative array with `get_object_vars()`, you can then get the keys from this with `array_keys()`:

```
$keysFromObject = array_keys(get_object_vars($anObject));
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like array_keys might have stopped working on objects but, amazingly, the foreach construct works, at least on a php stdClass object.

```
$object = new stdClass();
$object->a = 20;
$object->b = "hello";
$keys = array_keys($object);
// array_keys returns null. PHP Version 7.3.3 windows
foreach($object as $key=>$value)
{
     // but this works
     echo("key:" . $key . " value:" . $value . "\n");
}
```