# Checking first level of JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON object as follows:

```
$data = [{"articles": {"ID":  5, "NAME": "BIKE"},{"ID": 6, "NAME": "CAR"}}
```

So, I need to know that what kind of info coming from client, in this case "articles". How can I check first level of this JSON object by PHP?

Comment: Have you tried [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: The data you supplied isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @Kelly I used to Blackberry for this message so can't control too much, sorry about that!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Print keys from an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803881/php-print-keys-from-an-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = json_decode('
{
  "articles": [
    {"ID":  5, "NAME": "BIKE"},
    {"ID": 6, "NAME": "CAR"}
  ]
}');
$keys = array_keys((array)$data);
echo $keys[0]; //displays: articles
```

Here is your data as a valid json (your code is invalid). This typecasted `$data` as an array so that `array_keys()` will not complain about passing an object.

Comment: You could also just pass true as the second argument to json_decode to get an array.

Comment: Great point. I was just thinking maybe he wanted to preserve the object. Good addition!

Answer (score 2):

Read commented line bellow to know detail

```
<?php
    //$data = '[{"articles": {"ID":  5, "NAME": "BIKE"},{"ID": 6, "NAME": "CAR"}}';

    //Your json data should be like this
    $data = '{"articles": [{"ID":  5, "NAME": "BIKE"},{"ID": 6, "NAME": "CAR"}]}';

    $data_decoded = json_decode($data);

    foreach($data_decoded as $key=>$value) {
        //first level of json object as many as its items
        echo $key; 
        //var_dump($key,$value);   
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i would use `$json = json_decode($data, true);` this will convert the json string to a associative array so you can use it like any other array

take a look at this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all, by the way.