# PHP get keys from array in object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I've got object and I need list of it's keys.

for now I doing that in foreach

```
foreach($obj as $key => $attribute){
  var_dump($key);
}
```

Is there some PHP built in function for getting object keys like `array_keys` for arrays?

trace

> object(Solarium\QueryType\Select\Result\Document)#1383 (1) {
>   ["fields":protected]=> array(31) { ["pdf_url"]=> string(51)
>   "xxxxxxxxxxxx" ["title"]=>
>   string(150) ......

Comment: show your $obj.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22462689/6374322

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22462689/4248328

Comment: There is `get_object_vars()` at http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Comment: You can use `get_object_vars()` PHP function

Comment: get_object_vars() return empty array. But foreach do the job. I don't know why.

Comment: @StevanTosic show us your $obj

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Print keys from an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803881/php-print-keys-from-an-object)

Comment: Or cast to array (`$arr = (array) $obj;`) then use `array_keys($arr)`

Comment: What is your complexity?? and what you want to do?? _PHP get object keys_ is not enough to help you, share what you have. Your try is correct..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class A 
{
    private $a = 1;
    protected $b = 2;
    public $c = 3;
}

$object = new A();
$fields = get_object_vars($object);
```

But by this method, you can only get **public** fields from your object,
i.e

```
print_r($fields);
```

Will output

```
Array ( [c] => 3 )
```

Comment: I tried get_object_vars but it return empty array. I now see that I wrote wrong question because it was array in object, and there is no public property in obj.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is because it was

> array in object.

I solve problem with this

```
array_keys($obj->getFields())
```