# Get property names from PHP stdClass

Tags: php, object

I have an array object that looks like:

```
$inDatabase = Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [abc@gmail.com] => Array
                (
                )
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [xyz@gmail.com] => Array
                (
                )
        )
)
```

How do I push email addresses onto a new array?  I tried the following:

```
$innerKeys =[];
$temp=[];
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
   $temp = array_keys($inDatabase[$i])

   //so I thought $temp[0] would have the email address but $temp is null.

   array_push($innerKeys,$temp[0]);

}
```

Comment: Why are you using email addresses as property names in the first place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Print keys from an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803881/php-print-keys-from-an-object)

Comment: Much simpler with no looping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_keys()` is for arrays. To turn the object properties into an array, use `get_object_vars()`. So you want

```
$temp = array_keys(get_object_vars($inDatabase[$i]));
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/nAwKGj)

Comment: this produces no output.  print_r($temp) is blank

Comment: I mistyped the array name, did you copy my mistake?

Comment: BTW, why don't you use `foreach`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_reduce()`, `get_object_vars()`, and `array_keys()`.

```
$emails = array_reduce($inDatabase, function ($arr, $obj) {
    return array_merge($arr, array_keys(get_object_vars($obj)));
}, []);
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/IU3C9

Answer (score 1):

You can also just cast to an array and get the first key.  I modified it a bit:

```
foreach($inDatabase as $o) {
   $innerKeys[] = array_keys((array)$o)[0];
}
```

However, since you want the first one, `key` (surprisingly) will work on an object:

```
foreach($inDatabase as $o) {
   $innerKeys[] = key($o);
}
```

Or much simpler:

```
$innerKeys = array_map('key', $inDatabase);
```