# PHP Undefined index of array. Why?

Tags: php, arrays

This is... I don't even know what this is happening.

```
// var_dump of items before
object(stdClass)[84]
   public '75' => object(stdClass)[87]

$items = (array) $items; // Casting unserialized stdClass to array
var_dump($items);

//Result of var dump:
array
  '75' => 
    object(stdClass)[87]

//Now lets get this item:
var_dump($items[75]); // Error
var_dump($items['75']); // Error
```

What the?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to cast into a different variable `$new_items = (array) $items; var_dump($new_items[75]);`

Comment: This gives me the same result.

Comment: [Reproducible Example](http://codepad.org/cRX75sye)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, you are using a debug extension, so the `var_dump()` output is different then standart library, properties can not be numeric but `$obj->{'75'}` is okay.
If can you reach to the sub object by `$items->{'75'}` yes you have a numeric property. 
otherwise you can try `print_r($items);` and see the original output, or check the array after `get_object_vars()`

```
    <?php

$items = new stdClass();
$items->{'75'} = new stdClass();
$items->{'75'}->{'85'} = new stdClass();


$items = (array) $items; // Casting unserialized stdClass to array
$items_array = get_object_vars($items); // getting object vars as an array.

var_dump($items["75"]); // Error
var_dump($items['75']); // Error
var_dump($items_array['75']); // Works
```

PHP issue :  [#45959](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45959)

Read the casting blockquote: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting

Comment: Yes, when $items is still an object I CAN reach the "75" with `$obj->{'75'}`.

Please, look: http://pastebin.com/nTbGscD5

Comment: so, you have to use get_object_vars();

Comment: It worked, thanks. It was weird, because I've used array_keys on the $items after casting it to array and it worked.

Comment: +1 Awesome research @TufanBarışYıldırım - Thanks for digging up that tidbit about casting objects to arrays. Explains everything nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Casting to an array doesn't work like that.

See here: [get_object_vars() vs. cast to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512212/get-object-vars-vs-cast-to-array)

and here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting

> Blockquote
>   "If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable names, with a few notable exceptions: integer properties are unaccessible; private variables have the class name prepended to the variable name; protected variables have a '*' prepended to the variable name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side.